# Dynamic Date in Excel Cubeelement

Tags: excel, mdx, cube

I would like to set the parameter of the expression for a `cubeelement` that is described by:

```
=CUBEELEMENT("ThisWorkbookDataModel";"[Kalender].[Date].&[2020-08-04T00:00:00]")
```

to set on todays date and then, in the next seven cells the next seven days.

Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I used cube formulas in `Excel` but is the parameter a string that can use references to cell values?

So say cell `A1` has the year 2008 in it then the formula could be this:

```
=CUBEELEMENT("ThisWorkbookDataModel";"[Kalender].[Date].&[" & A1 & "-08-04T00:00:00]")
```

Then if you put 2009 in cell `A2` you should be able to reuse the above.

A similar approach as used above for years can be applied to the last 7 days.

Hopefully this helps.